# Combining three functions

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop

*I have created the following scripts:
1. function1 takes data from yahoo finance and puts it into DataFrame and does this for all stocks
2. function2 performs a rolling regression and saves the residuals to a list.
I want to repeat function 2 for each stock in function1, take the standard deviation of the residuals, whilst saving the output to a final list.
I seem to be unable to figure out how to combine these functions. Any help would much appreciated.*

UPDATE:

- The problem I have now is that the script only works for the last stock in stock_list. Ie. the script only appends one number to the xx list instead of looping through all stocks and taking (0,90) ranges from each stock and then appending a stdev number for each.

I am uncertain about how to use both for stock in stock_list and for n in range(0,90) when I am executing the last function (stdev(xx, xxx).

Any help much appreciated!

updated code below:

```
def stockprice(stock, y, X, xx, xxx):
        try:
            start = datetime.datetime(2016,8,1)
            end = datetime.datetime(2017,1,1)
            f = web.get_data_yahoo(stock, start, end, interval='d')
            f.drop(f.columns[[0,1,2,3,4]], axis=1, inplace=True)
            f['LnReturn'] = np.log(f['Adj Close']) - np.log(f['Adj Close'].shift(1))
            data2 = pd.concat([f,kf], axis = 1)
            data2['XRtrn'] = (data2['LnReturn']*100 - data2['RF'])
            df = data2[np.isfinite(data2['XRtrn'])]
            df = pd.DataFrame(df)
            y = df['XRtrn'].shift(-1)
            y = y.dropna()
            y = pd.DataFrame(y)
            x = df.ix[:,[2,3,4]]
            x = x[:-1]
            X = sm.add_constant(x)
        except:
            xx.append(['nan'])
        return y, X, xx, xxx

def regression(n, y, X, xx, xxx):
                try:
                    model = sm.OLS(y[n:(90+n)], X[n:(90+n)])
                    results = model.fit()
                    r2 = results.rsquared
                    xxx.append(r2)
                except:
                    xxx.append(['nan'])
                return y, X, xx, xxx

def stdev(xx, xxx):
                try:
                    xxx1 = pd.DataFrame(xxx)
                    std = xxx1.std()
                    stdv = std.tolist()
                    xx.append(stdv)
                except:
                    xxx.append(['nan'])
                return xx, xxx

# set the initial value for the variables you will use later on
xx = []
xxx = []
X = []
y = []

for stock in stock_list:
    y, X, xx, xxx = stockprice(stock, y, X, xx, xxx)

for n in range(0,90):
    y, X, xx, xxx = regression(n, y, X, xx, xxx)

xx, xxx = stdev(xx, xxx)
```

Comment: return df from function1 and take it as parameter from function2?

Comment: Sorry, new to Python. Not sure what that means .. Would you be able to demonstrate with an example?

Comment: Basically you're not using functions in their intended way. Your function should (usually) end with a `return` value so that you can access it _outside_ of a function. Currently when the function completes, everything is thrown away. Equally, you don't pass arguments to the function. The idea being that the function does a standard thing but to a range of inputs, not just one specific set of data. It would be better for you to read some tutorials on functions rather than us give an answer - you will _need_ this knowledge to do anything useful.

Comment: Also, these concepts are not confined to Python but most programming languages.

Comment: Having gone through a few tutorials I am having problems relating back to what I want to do. Is there a specific example you could point to which would make it easier to learn from? Thank you

Comment: I am a bit uncertain about what my return values should be. And how do I then call these in the second function?

Whenever I have tried to set x and y as the return values in function 1 to then call them in function 2 I get Nan in my output.

Comment: I just posted an answer with a simple example. The problem you had is that you are declaring your variables outside your functions and using them inside your functions, which is a bad practice (or a mistake in most cases). You should provide your variables as input parameters and return the modified inputs in the end, being careful to update them after the function call. Please let me know if this solves your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your code is supposed to do or what your variables are, but I think you could do something like this (you will need adjustments, but I just want you to understand the principles used):

```
def function1(stock, kf, xx, X): # provide all varibles you will use as parameters
    try:
        ## your code here, using stock, kf, xx and/or X
    except:
        ## your code here, using stock, kf, xx and/or X
    return kf, xx, X # return all variables you will need on next steps, except 'stock' because it will be managed by the for-loop

def function2(n, y, X, xxx, xx): # provide all varibles you will use as parameters
    try:
        ## your code here, using n, y, X, xxx and/or  xx
    except:
        ## your code here, using n, y, X, xxx and/or  xx
    return y, X, xxx, xx # return all variables you will need on next steps, except 'n' because it will be managed by the for-loop


# set the initial value for the variables you will use later on
kf = ***whatever***
xx = ***whatever***
xxx = ***whatever***
X = ***whatever***
Y = ***whatever***


for stock in stock_list:
    kf, xx, X = function1(stock, kf, xx, X)

for n in range(0,90):
    y, X, xxx, xx = function2(n, y, X, xxx, xx)
```

Please let me know if it solves your problem

Comment: [peet-peeve]Python has no concept of variable declaration. Variables spring into existence when they are assigned to.[/pet-peeve]

Comment: yeah... you are right. What I meant was "set the initial values for your variables"... I just chose the wrong words. Thanks for the comment! I will update my answer accordingly

Comment: Good. Gooooood.

Comment: Thank you caspillaga - much much clearer! I have updated the code above. Having troubles figuring out how to use both the for stock in stock_list and for n in range in the last function (stdev()). Right now I only get the value of the last stock appended to my final list (xx).